# Flex 4, php & common db variables

Tags: apache-flex, zend-framework

I am using Flex 4, Zend & PHP. I created a few php dataservices & modified them to create 1 php file w/ my database connections that will then be used throughout my service calls in flex. I tested my php using just php & everything works fine.

When I test it in Flex, though, I get an error "Make sure that Zend Framework is installed correctly and the parameter "amf.production" is not set to true".

I've tracked it down to the first line in my code below that has an "include" statement...it's not a php error as the script works in php. What is the workaround for Flex?

```
<?php

include ( "myConnections.php" ); // flex doesn't like this line
class myCustomClass {

 public $conn;

 public function __construct() {

   $this->conn = new conn();

   $this->connection = mysqli_connect(
       $this->conn->server,
       $this->conn->username,
       $this->conn->password,
       $this->conn->databasename,
       $this->conn->port
        );

}


public function myFunction () {

    // blah, blah, blah
}

}
?>
```

Comment: did you remove that line and try again?

Comment: yes, if I remove that line & put my database variables directly in the file then it works fine...but that defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do, which is to have my db connections in 1 file & access that file from various php dataservices, rather than list my db connections in each php dataservice

Comment: i just find it ironic that when you add a new dataservice flex 4 will point you toward this object-oriented style of php but then not allow you to take full advantage of oo.....

Comment: this helped me:
http://corlan.org/2009/06/12/working-in-flash-builder-4-with-flex-and-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Zend framework , you shouldn't have to use include statements, rather use the Bootstrap file to set your environment.

This being said, are you sure that there isn't a problem with myConnections.php? Just for debug purposes , have you tried to hardcode your connection values and then test with Flex?

Comment: connection values are fine. As I stated above, I see the results from my mysql query when I am using just php...the problem is integrating it w/ Flex/Zend. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: When I require_once('path/to/my/file.php') I get an error "Make sure that Zend Framework is installed correctly and the parameter "amf.production" is not set to true in the amf_config.ini file located in the project output folder"

Comment: having common database variables is standard practice in php...why didn't the flex team think of this before they rolled this out?

Comment: I'm not sure that's what the problem is really, i rather think your problem is either with your Zend Framework structure or more simply within the myConnections.php file. I use ZF & FlashBuilder very often and it works pretty well...

Comment: I also use ZF & FlashBuilder as well & they work but that isn't my question.

Comment: isn't it?!... if it works pretty well why the problem? you're assuming that there's a problem with Flex as opposed to a problem in your code, hence the comment i made. just trying to help here so the next time you post a comment , let's try to make it a little more constructive, try for instance to give us the results of your debugging efforts. have you actually tried to hardcode values and test with Flex, what was the result, did it work? if yes, then you may want to look at your ZF structure and instead of using include , use the Bootstrap file , as recommended earlier...

Comment: also try looking into Zend_Config_Ini & Zend_Registry to set your database access as opposed to using your myConnections.php file...

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the parentheses so it says  `include "myConnections.php";` 
Or use require once? Or use AutoLoad( http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php )?

Comment: each of your suggestions work fine until I try them with flex

Answer (score 0):

Try this way: include 'myConnections.php'; With single quote.

But 100% problem is in your php code. If it possible add myConnections.php code.